# How to add a new architecture to gem5?

Tags: gem5

Is it possible to add a new architecture to gem5 library? If I can add, then what is the procedure to do so. And is there any documents which can help me. I just want to add POWER-PC architecture though it has power architecture in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy one of the better maintained existing ISAs (X86, ARM or RISCV seem to be the best maintained to me), mass find and replace old ISA to new ISA name in all files, and then start hacking it up to look like your ISA.

Basic userland syscall emulation is likely feasible for one person to achieve (depending on how well you know your ISA and gem5), but I suspect full system would be months of work.